# large file upload via Zuul

Tags: upload, large-files, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm trying to upload a large file through Zuul.

Basically I have the applications set up like this:

- UI: this is where the Zuul Gateway is located
- Backend: this is where the file must finally arrive.

I used the functionality described [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_uploading_files_through_zuul) so everything works fine if I used "Transfer-Encoding: chunked". However, this can only be set via curl. I haven't found any way to set this header in the browser (the header is rejected with the error message in the console "*Refused to set unsafe header ..*".

Any idea how to instruct the header to set this header ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that actually there are 2 possible ways to upload large files via zuul:

1. By using "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" in header (but this cannot be used in a browser, as mentioned in the initial question, because this header is considered unsafe)
2. By bypassing the DispatcherServlet servlet used by zuul (using the /zuul path in front of the usual path that I was using).

I found the documentation not very clear in this aspect (that you can use either of the 2 options). In my case, considering that the file was being uploaded via Angular Js (hence in the browser), I had to use the second approach.